# One-half factor representing power or energy

Tags: energy, non-linear-optics

In a book on optical solitons, the following is said-

When loss or gain is taken into account, the equation -

$-i\frac{\partial u}{\partial z} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2} + |u|^2u$ becomes

$-i\frac{\partial u}{\partial z} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2} + |u|^2u - i\frac{1}{2}\alpha u$

where a positive or negative value of $\alpha$ implies gain or loss respectively. **The factor of one-half in the $\alpha$ term causes $\alpha$ itself to represent power (or energy) loss or gain per unit length.**

I don't understand why the factor of one-half implies that $\alpha$ is the power or energy.

Edit: The complex quantity $u(z,t)$ is a value proportional to the light field, $z$ is distance along the propagation direction and $t$ is time. $i$ is just the usual $\sqrt{-1}$.

Comment: Please explain what each symbol in your equations means.

Comment: Added to the end of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the power and energy are proportional to two factors of field. Thus, for exponential decay, the power loss parameter is twice the field loss parameter.

The [Poynting vector $\mathbf{S}$](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting_vector) is the energy flowing per unit area per unit time of an electromagnetic field (or power per unit area):
$$
\mathbf{S} = \mathbf{E} \times \mathbf{H}
$$
So if $\mathbf{E}$ and $\mathbf{H}$ both decay/gain as $e^{-\beta z}$, then $\mathbf{S}$ will decay/gain as $e^{-2\beta z}$. Therefore, the energy decay rate $\alpha$ is twice the field decay rate:
$$
\alpha = 2\beta.
$$

So if $\alpha$ represents power loss, then you need to multiply by $1/2$ to get back to field loss.

Comment: As a non-physicist, the statement "power and energy are proportional to two factors of field" does not make too much sense. Could you please explain further or link a good resource?

Comment: @Paddy Fair enough! Is my edit helpful?

Comment: Yep, that works! Thanks